# check server speed / response time

Tags: web-hosting, server, performance

I was reeled in by cheap, unlimited hosting. (Well, kind of cheap apart from having to buy a year upfront.)  The moral of the story is it's awful. I'm trying to find a reason for them to let me leave and I've seen on there site they say "fast a reliable hosting" (big lie).

Whats the best way for me to check the server speed response time so i can use this in my argument and hopefully be let go ?

This has nothing to do with page speed, only server speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't measure only server speed, that server has to do something so you only can measure how some page (server side code) is performing on that server. You can't mesure your code since they can say that your code is slow. One way is to take known software and put that and measure performance, something like [PHP Benchmark Performance Script](http://www.free-webhosts.com/php-benchmark-script.php), that script is created primarily for that, to compare php hosting, of course if your server supports PHP. You can then compare your results with [other sites](http://www.free-webhosts.com/php-hosting-comparison.php).

You can use Google Analytics and monitor Site Speed (under Content menu), if there are big differences this can be a sign of busy server with lot's of sites, but frankly all cheap hostings are like that.

Comment: ive had a look under the site speed > page timing in analytics, and it was saying "Avg. Page Load Time (sec) 0" pageviews "465", any idea what those figures might mean ? Also is there some sort of ping test for servers ?

Comment: don't know, it seems like there is no timings at all. For ping test better ask on serverfault.com